# How to rate tweet comment as positive or negative using Word Sentiment

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I want to categorize  comments as positive or negative based on the content.
This is a problem of NLP(Natural Lang Processing) and i am finding difficulties in implementing this.

Comment: Difficulties as in?

Could you tell us about something you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this blog post](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/twitter-sentiment-analysis-using-python-and-nltk/). The author describes how to build a Twitter Sentiment Classifier with Python and NLTK. Looks like a good start, as sentiment analysis is no easy task with lots of active research going on in the field.

Also [search SO for Sentiment Analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sentiment%20analysis), I believe there already are many useful answers about this topic on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Here is, Combination of Semi Supervised co-occurance based and unsupervised WSD based classifier. Its in Python though. And you need nltk, wordnet, SentiWord-net and movie review corpus which comes with nltk.

https://github.com/kevincobain2000/sentiment_classifier

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite complex, anyway I love [Pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern): http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-examples-elections

Answer (score 0):

If you are not categorizing a lot of comments you may wish to try using the [chatterboax API](http://cbanalytics.co.uk/api/)

Else you can use [Linpipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/), but you will have to train your models